# Adding fruits to a basket, allowing selection from ID and name

Tags: python

I'm writing a tool which users can select multiple choices at once. Whilst I can't provide the actual content, I've replicated it with fruit. I'm replicating some functionality from Nikto where it allows different flags like "-mutation abcd".

for example here we have three fruits:

```
1- apple
2- orange
3- kiwi
```

I wanna let users to type "12" or "appleorange" or "21" or "orangeapple" for selecting apple and orange, or "123" or "appleorangekiwi" or vice versa to select apple, orange and kiwi and etc.

Assume that there are more than 3 choices, so it would be pain in the neck if I want to write elif statement for all multiple selections.
How can I make my code simpler and shorter?

Here is my code:

```
fruits_ls = []


def add_fruits():
    while True:
        print("choose your favorite fruits:\n"
            "1- apple\n"
            "2- orange\n"
            "3- kiwi\n"
            "4- exit\n")

        my_fruits = input()
        if my_fruits == str(1) or my_fruits == "apple":
            fruits_ls.append("Apple")
        elif my_fruits == str(2) or my_fruits == "orange":
            fruits_ls.append("Orange")
        elif my_fruits == str(3) or my_fruits == "kiwi":
            fruits_ls.append("Kiwi")
        elif my_fruits == str(12) or my_fruits == "appleorange" or my_fruits == str(21) or my_fruits == "orangeapple":
            fruits_ls.append("Apple")
            fruits_ls.append("Orange")

        elif my_fruits == str(13) or my_fruits == "applekiwi" or my_fruits == str(31) or my_fruits == "kiwiapple":
            fruits_ls.append("Apple")
            fruits_ls.append("Kiwi")

        elif my_fruits == str(23) or my_fruits == "orangekiwi" or my_fruits == str(32) or my_fruits == "kiwiorange":
            fruits_ls.append("Orange")
            fruits_ls.append("Kiwi")

        elif my_fruits == str(4) or my_fruits == "exit":
            break


add_fruits()

print(fruits_ls)
```

Comment: @sf31 Have you looking into the existing parsing facilities of `argparse`? Idk if it does this, but have you checked?

Comment: @CodeCaster Please provide answers in answers, not in comments.

Comment: @Peilonrayz that was not an answer, not even a partial one. It was a warning towards the OP, so they could mention that in their question.

Comment: @CodeCaster It was more than enough to be an answer on Code Review. Note that all critiques of code are answer material, and so warnings on edge cases or unforeseen input are fair game in answers.

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica

I just skimmed it, seems helpful, I'll work on it. Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Creating a mapping from input to output can be very useful here. A dictionary is the ideal data structure for this

```
VALID_INPUTS = {
    '1': 'Apple',
    'apple': 'Apple',
    '2': 'Orange',
    'orange': 'Orange',
    '3': 'Kiwi',
    'kiwi': 'Kiwi',
}
EXIT_INPUTS = ['4', 'exit']
```

Then you can loop over this mapping and append the matching inputs

```
if my_fruits in EXIT_INPUTS:
    break
for valid_input, fruit in VALID_INPUTS.items():
    if valid_input in my_fruits:
         fruits_ls.append(fruit)
```

Comment: A note for op if he opts to use this implementation: you'll need to reconfigure how you exit the while loop. A simple input asking if the user wants to enter more options that trips a boolean controlling the while loop would work

Comment: That's true, you can create another data structure to store these exit inputs (a list for example) and test for the input being one of them

Comment: this would fail if there are more than 10 elements

Comment: Thx. Currently I'm at work and don't access to my system, I'll test the code above and let you know about that.

Comment: @hjpotter92 Why is that? I'm not aware of any limit on the size of dictionaries, arrays or tuples, apart from what your machine can manage. (In general, it's more helpful to say "this would fail *because*...". If someone thinks that's incorrect, they can provide a correction more easily. And if you're right, then other people have learnt something. :)

Comment: @Graham you're right. for eg. consider 10=pineapple, 11=guava; how would input `114` or `1104` be parsed?

Comment: @hjpotter92 Ah, I see your point.  That's not really related to this answer, I think, more to do with the OP's scenario in general?  The obvious answer though is to go base-36, where your options go from 0-9 and then from A-Z.  (Note for OP: "0" makes a nice consistent exit condition.)  Conceptually this could be increased to base-<max-Unicode-value>, although exceeding alphanumeric characters should be a pretty clear hint to the OP that their scheme has reached its practical limits.

Comment: Both solutions which @IainShelvington and c4iimeco4ch provide work well, but there is an issue in both, if users type 12, and again type 12 or appleorange, the output would be Apple, Orange, Apple, Orange. How to solve this problem? so that the program doesn't get users' inputs more than once. e.g: it only accepts Apple once.

Comment: @c4llmeco4ch Read the previous comment of mine plz.

Comment: Simply add ``` and '<fruitnamehere>' not in fruits_ls ``` to the end of each if. This confirms the item is not already in the cart before adding it. You will need to add parens around the or section of the if

Comment: @sf31 instead of fruit_ls being a list, create a set

Answer (score 3):

The first thing I would like to do is applaud you for not immediately turning to back-to-back if statements. It's a trap I commonly see when tackling these kinds of problems. However, in this case, I'd ask a question that is counter to my previous point: are your options mutually exclusive? In other words, is it a problem if a person has multiple options in a loop accepted? Given you are accepting inputs like 31 or 12, my expectation is no. As such, instead of:

```py
if my_fruits == str(1) or my_fruits == "apple":
    fruits_ls.append("Apple")
elif my_fruits == str(2) or my_fruits == "orange":
    fruits_ls.append("Orange")
elif my_fruits == str(3) or my_fruits == "kiwi":
    fruits_ls.append("Kiwi")
elif my_fruits == str(12) or my_fruits == "appleorange" or my_fruits == str(21) or my_fruits == "orangeapple":
    fruits_ls.append("Apple")
    fruits_ls.append("Orange")

elif my_fruits == str(13) or my_fruits == "applekiwi" or my_fruits == str(31) or my_fruits == "kiwiapple":
    fruits_ls.append("Apple")
    fruits_ls.append("Kiwi")

elif my_fruits == str(23) or my_fruits == "orangekiwi" or my_fruits == str(32) or my_fruits == "kiwiorange":
    fruits_ls.append("Orange")
    fruits_ls.append("Kiwi")

elif my_fruits == str(4) or my_fruits == "exit":
    break
```

A possibility would be checking if an instance of an option is inside the input:

```py
if '1' in my_fruits or 'apple' in my_fruits:
    fruits_ls.append('Apple')
if '2' in my_fruits or 'orange' in my_fruits:
    fruits_ls.append('Orange')
if '3' in my_fruits or 'kiwi' in my_fruits:
    fruits_ls.append('Kiwi')
if '4' == my_fruits:
    break
```

There are some small problems with the above solution that may or may not be in scope. For example, "121" will only give "AppleOrange" when "AppleOrangeApple" may be desired. I can provide further insight if this is the case.

Hopefully this helps. Assuming the need for elifs is always a safe bet at first, but when refactoring code, elifs can be ditched if the answers can coexist without hindering the code's performance. Let me know if I can help further.

Comment: I guess this is the correct answer, I'll check the code tonight and let you know.
Fortunately there is no option like "121".
So you mean that I should change elifs and rewrite the code like the "ifs" you provided, right? because I have some other functions which works almost like this one.

Comment: Right. The idea is elifs imply one or the other can happen, but not both. Like in a sports game, both teams cannot win at the same time. However, this problem does not have that concern. A user can have both an apple and a kiwi at the same time. Thus, we can use ifs rather than being concerned with elifs.

Comment: Even if they are not mutually exclusive, you can adopt a data structure and a loop to make it more clear and expendable, as in https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/234504/123200

Answer (score 3):

This could be made into a generic function that accepts a list of items.  It displays a menu based on the list and lets the user select one or more items from the menu.  Rather than keep a global list, the function returns the list of select items.

```
def select_items(prompt, items):
    selected_items = set()

    while True:
        print(f"{prompt}:")
        for n, item in enumerate(items, 1):
            print(f"    {n:2} - {item}")
        exit_no = n+1
        print(f"    {exit_no:2} - exit")

        raw_selection = input("> ")
        selection = raw_selection.lower()

        for n, item in enumerate(items, 1):
            if item in selection or str(n) in selection:
                selected_items.add(item)

        if 'exit' in selection or str(exit_no) in selection:
            return selected_items


select_items("Choose your favorite fruits", "apple orange kiwi banana".split())
```

Comment: It works but the issue is still there, if users type each item again and again, the item will be shown in the output twice. like: Choose your favorite fruits: 1 Choose your favorite fruits: 1 Result: Apple, Apple

Comment: @sf31 - Then change `selected_items` to a `set()` instead of a list (see revised answer). Or check to see if the item is already in `selected_items` before appending it.